# Выборка в MySQL (статистика)

Tags: mysql, sql, статистика

Уважаемые, подскажите как найти решение для такой задачи.

**Есть БД с такой структурой:**

**date**................... **id_man**..............**nomer**

02.04.2019.............1.................123456

02.04.2019.............1.................123456

02.04.2019.............1.................147147

02.04.2019.............2.................987167

.......

Необходимо сделать статистику (**посуточную**)

**1)** сколько всего номеров было внесено в БД (*этот вопрос я решил так:* 
`SELECT date, COUNT(*) FROM mybase WHERE date LIKE '02.04.2019'`);

**2)** Сколько **всего номеров** внес определенный человек (**id_man**);

**3)** Сколько **уникальных номеров** внес определенный человек (**id_man**) (частично получилось отдельно таким запросом: `SELECT date, id_man, nomer, COUNT(*) FROM mybase WHERE (date = '02.04.2019') GROUP BY id_man, nomer`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это все сделать одним запросом к mysql, чтобы в итоге получилось примерно так (вложенные selectы?):

**date**................**id_man**...............**total**..................**unique**........

02.04.2019.......... 1 .................... 3 ........................ 2............

Comment: вообще уникальные `count(distinct nomer)` и группировать по нему не надо. И сколько всего в БД в тех же строках, где количества по отдельным людям (при group by id_man) можно получить только подзапросом.

Comment: Mike, я вас попрошу, можете привести пример подзапроса в этом случае?

Comment: в качестве подзапроса выступает ваш первый запрос, только с одной колонкой count(*) или count(distinct nomer) (смотря что имеется ввиду под фразой "сколько всего номеров в БД"